# Video uploaded using YouTube Data API v3 is not showing video file name on YouTube website

Tags: c#, youtube-api, filenames

We have encountered an issue related to uploaded video file name (Raw file) which is showing “unknown” on YouTube website instead of uploaded file name.

We are using the YouTube Data API v3 to interact with YouTube from an ASP.Net C# web application, which uses the Google APIs Client Library for .NET.

During testing we have noticed that all the videos uploaded by using YouTube Data API v3 are not showing video file name (Raw file) on YouTube website under the “VIDEO INFORMATION” section. We didn’t see this issue in previous YouTube Data API v2.

FYI we have followed YouTube .Net example code to upload video https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

We haven’t find any information on Reference guide of YouTube Data API v3 which help us to find out how to set video file name at the time of upload.

Could anyone please advise regarding the aforementioned issue?

**Sample Code**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
    /// <summary>
    /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: upload a video.
   /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
   /// See https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted
  /// </summary>
  internal class UploadVideo
  {
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
  Console.WriteLine("==============================");

  try
  {
    new UploadVideo().Run().Wait();
  }
  catch (AggregateException ex)
  {
    foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private async Task Run()
{
  UserCredential credential;
  using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
        // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None
    );
  }

  var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
  });

  var video = new Video();
  video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
  video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
  video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
  video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
  video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
  video.Status = new VideoStatus();
  video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
  var filePath = @"REPLACE_ME.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
  {
    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

    await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
  }
}

void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
{
  switch (progress.Status)
  {
    case UploadStatus.Uploading:
      Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
      break;

    case UploadStatus.Failed:
      Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
      break;
  }
}

void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
}
```

}
}

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Many thanks for considering my question. Actually, I did provide the sample code link in my initial post but never mind please find sample code below. This problem is not related to usual C# issues; it requires some background of using YouTube Data API v3.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems an upstream bug: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7140